# Почему может выдавать 403 None Post запрос?

Tags: python-3.x, requests

```
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.8 Safari/537.36'}
    text = requests.get('https://zhukovsky.hh.ru/login', headers = headers).text
    post = requests.post(
    'https://zhukovsky.hh.ru/account/login?backurl=/',
    data={
        'backUrl': 'https://zhukovsky.hh.ru/',
        'failUrl': r'/account/login?backurl=%2F',
        'username': '@mail.ru',
        'password': '*****',
        'remember': 'yes',
        '_xsrf': self.xsrf(text)
    },
    allow_redirects=True,
    headers= headers,
  )
```

self.xsrf(text) отдает валидную строку.

Comment: `Код ответа на статус ошибки "HTTP 403 Forbidden" указывает, что сервер понял запрос, но отказывается его авторизовать.`. Похоже, что-то неправильно у вас. Посмотрите в `post.text` если что-нибудь -- сервер мог вернуть в странице пояснение что ему не понравилось

Comment: @gil9red он там html страницу отдает, чтобы вытащить xsrf. чисто код

Comment: @gil9red, я вас понял) Пишет доступ запрещен)

Comment: Попробуйте использовать сессии, вот пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/37100410de903d15088aaa1690e8d26552b5df35/requests__examples/upload_image_to_waifu2x_booru_pics/main.py#L22 Так же посмотрите в инспекторе браузера как сформирован запрос и повторите его. Пример включения отладочных сообщений в requests: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/37100410de903d15088aaa1690e8d26552b5df35/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py